# PHP Session In 2 Web Application

Tags: php, session

I have 2 web application in my Notebook, now every I want to logout from one application, another application that still logged in will logout too.

In my App1, I using session :

```
session_start();
$session = $_SESSION['username_a'];
```

and in App2 :

```
session_start();
$session = $_SESSION['username_packing'];
```

Finally the logout PHP code like this :

```
session_destroy();
```

The condition : If I was logged in with 2 Application and then I logout 1 application, another 1 application will logout too.

My question is : Is there anyway to prevent that (If log out 1 application, then another application will stay logged in)?

Comment: You have to record the session in server side and invalidate the recorded session when user logs out.

Comment: Why do not use Unset. E.g unset($_SESSION["username_a"])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session_destroy will destroy all session. You should unset specific session. Like this:

```
unset($_SESSION['username_a']); // on App 1
```

and

```
unset($_SESSION['username_packing']); // on App2
```